# Rails API - service as consumer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I have been looking around the web, but haven't found anything that can give me a satisfying answer.

## Setting:

We have a Rails app which is up and running using Devise for user authentication.

I am now starting to expand the app and add an API to it.

The API will be consumed by mobile apps and other services.

Could anyone point me in the right direction regarding authentication for the part where other services will consume my API and determine whether it is a service or a user consuming it?

Should I just add an attribute to the user model saying this is used by a different service? Would it be better to implement a system with private and public API keys? How does this work?

Any advice and reading material is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda difficult from your question to understand what you want, if you're developing APIs for your server and your concern is just how to log in you have different ways to do it.

- Using the cookies in the same way as the other web requests (it's not the most elegant way to do it but it works)
- Using a gem that will implement Oauth you will just need part of it, just the part that will create the auth and the refresh token (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-devise-and-omniauth-for-your-rails-application could be a way)
- Using JWT (https://medium.com/@goncalvesjoao/rails-devise-jwt-and-the-forgotten-warden-67cfcf8a0b73)

See what is the best for your needs